# How to display a specific dicom image (Papaya)?

Tags: javascript, dicom, papaya

I am using the rii-mango/Papaya to display dicom-files. I upload a folder containing 243 dicom files. It always starts in the middle of the files (here image 121) but I want to start with image 243. Is there a function to display a specific image? I tried:

papayaContainers[0].preferences.viewer.currentSlice = 243;

But it does not work (nothing changes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify a `coordinate` parameter.  The coordinate is in image indices.  You'd need to know the image dimensions beforehand though.

```
params["coordinate"] = [0, 0, 0];
```

Another way would be to use the `loadingComplete` callback:

```
params["loadingComplete"] = function() {
    var viewer = papayaContainers[0].viewer;
    var dims = viewer.volume.header.imageDimensions;

    // position coordinate centered on last slice (assuming axial slices)
    var coord = new papaya.core.Coordinate(
        Math.floor(dims.xDim / 2), 
        Math.floor(dims.yDim / 2), 
        dims.zDim - 1);
    viewer.gotoCoordinate(coord);
};
```